# Array Map With Empty Array

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

In merging two arrays similar to the simplified ones below, one of them is sometimes initially empty.

`$newFields` is always populated as an array from a database query when the page is opened and gets merged with the second value from `$rowView` but only when an entry on the page has been opened.

The problem is, with $newFields empty, the value from $rowView appears in its place and that is what I am trying to stop and make it have no value instead.

```
// If entry not opened, initialize array
$rowView = is_array($rowView) ? $rowView : [];

$newArray = array_map(function ($n) use ($rowView) {
    if (substr($n, 0, 1) === '$' && !empty($rowView)) :
        $k = substr($n, 1);
        return $rowView[$k];
    endif;
    return $n;
}, $newFields);

// Array $rowView is only when an entry has been opened
// otherwise it is empty
Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [Marque] => MarqueName
)

// Array $newArray empty
Array
(
    [0] => Marque
    [1] => Marque
    [2] => 
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 50
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 
)

// Array $newArray populated
Array
(
    [0] => Marque
    [1] => Marque
    [2] => MarqueName
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 50
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 
)
```

Comment: `$noNulls = array_filter($newFields, function($val) { return $val !== null; });` should remove your `null` values

Comment: The error is telling you that `$rowView` is `null` so what is `$rowView` supposed to be?

Comment: @Phil I added the output of $rowView to the question (sorry, I missed that when posting). On the $noNulls, I am unclear what to do with it. Can you provide more details or maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: You may think that `$rowView` is an array but the error message says otherwise

Comment: @Phil I used print_r($rowView) to give the results I posted. Would that work if it were not an array? It gived the error only what $rowView is empty, ie before it has received any values from a form.

Comment: Don't argue with error messages, they don't listen and are usually correct

Comment: Another things, in case you need to check the value is null or not, use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`

Comment: @Phil I actually agree with them and with you. In this case, it is not an array until the form has been submitted and it is giving the error before so you're right, it isn't an array. I suppose the question is, how to I make it be an array before it exists? Can it be initialized somehow? As I said, my little experience with arrays has quite faded.

Comment: @Allen Chak Thank you, I had forgotten about var_dump!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove empty array items with
[array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

or do this:

```
$newArray = array_filter(array_map(function ($n) use ($rowView) {
    if (substr($n, 0, 1) === '$' && !empty($rowView)) :
        $k = substr($n, 1);
        return $rowView[$k];
    endif;
    return $n;
}, $newFields));
```